# Is there a way to display any media, regardless of type? (especially in Django?)

Tags: javascript, python, django, image, video

If I have a .mp4 file, it will automatically display a video (flash?)
If it's a jpg, it'll just display the image...

Edit: I want this embedded inside a webpage.

Comment: Direct link works for most mainstream media formats...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you must have file view generator,

thats mean you have list of pic and video and then for each file generate correct player and tag

its easy

Comment: Where can I find a library for this?

Answer (score 1):

As eternicode says, all you need to do is make your views the normal way and pass the querysets to your template.

In the template , all you need to do is load the content from your query as part of `/media` as defined in your `settings.py` e.g

```
<img src="/media/{{model.object}}" width="135" height="60" alt="thumbnail" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need specify the "Content-Type" in the http response header.